# Access 2d array with point in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, pointers

I have a 2d array of a class. The size of array is very large (around 3000*3000) and accessing the array with ordinary row and column method is taking very much time. For this purpose, I want to use pointers to access the array.

Following is my array code:

Class definition:

```
Class BoxData     
{
  Size _bound;
  bool _isFilled=false;
  Color _color=Colors.White;

  public Size Bounds
  {
    get
    {
      return _bound;
    }
    set
    {
      _bound=value;
    }
  }

  public bool IsFilled
  {
    get
    {
      return _isFilled;
    }
    set
    {
      _isFilled=value;
    }
  }

  public Color FillColor
  {
    get
    {
      return _color;
    }
    set
    {
      _color=value;
    }
  }
}
```

Class used as array in application:

```
BoxData[,] boxData=new BoxData[3000,3000];
```

I want to access boxData with pointers.

Thanks

Comment: no you don't!...:) Suggest you post the (timed) code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use a Key Value Dictionary, using a key that is calculated using XY coordinates ?

Comment: @Mitch: I am just getting the bounds and colors from the array using loop.

Comment: @controlbreak: No, I didn't tried Key Value. How can I use it as arrays???

Comment: I am surprised, accessing an array is very fast. Do you mean it takes time to populate it the first time ? (3000x3000 iterations ?)

Comment: @controlbreak: Yes, 3000X3000 iterations (in some cases it is 5000x5000 or even more)

Comment: @Vinod Maurya You could replace Brush instead of Color and Freeze it to enhance the performance. Though the problem is not with the array iterations, unless you access the array in Column Order.

Answer (score 2):

Try a jagged array instead of a multi dimensional one, they are [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c) in Microsoft's CLR implementation

```
BoxData[][] boxData=new BoxData[3000][];
for (int i=0; i<3000; i++)
    boxData[i] = new BoxData[3000];
```

Comment: Good advice, but you should say why.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a struct instead of a class for BoxData ?

Struct is a value type: as you declare your array, everything will be populated already.
You will not longer use a loop to create `new BoxData()` instances.

```
var x = new BoxData[3000,3000]; // Populated array of BoxData
```

Because of struct vs class restrictions, you will have to remove initializers this way...

```
struct BoxData
{
    Size _bound;
    bool _isFilled; // = false;
    Color _color; // = Color.White;

    public Size Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            return _bound;
        }
        set
        {
            _bound = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsFilled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isFilled;
        }
        set
        {
            _isFilled = value;
        }
    }

    public Color FillColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _color;
        }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
        }
    }
}
```

...and initialize your default values using a loop will be much more faster.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        x[i, j].FillColor = Color.White;
```